# howto handle objects of private class, got as parameter

Tags: java

I learn Java at university and I have to do following excercise.
(simplified example)

```
import java.util.*;

public class A{
    private static class B{
        Integer b;
        private B(int b){this.b = b;}
    }

    private static class B_Comparable extends B implements     Comparable<B_Comparable> {
        private  B_Comparable(int b){super(b);}
        @Override
        public int compareTo(B_Comparable that) {
            return this.b.compareTo(that.b);
        }
    }

    private static class C<T> implements myList<T> { // see below
        private ArrayList<T> lst = new ArrayList<>();

        private static C<B_Comparable> createComparable() {
            C<B_Comparable> ust = new C<B_Comparable>();
            for (int i =0; i < 9; i++)
                ust.lst.add(new B_Comparable(i));
            return ust;
        }

        @Override
        public T fetch(int index){
             return lst.get(index);
        }
    }

    private void test(){
         C<B_Comparable> ustComparable = C.createComparable();
         A result = ClassD.handle(ustComparable,3,4);
    }
}

//--------------------------------------------------------

public class ClassD{
    public static <T, S> T handle( S ustC, int pos1, int pos2 ){ 
        // how can I compare elems of object ustC ?
        ustC.fetch(pos1).compareTo(ustC.fetch(pos2)); 
        //how can I fetch obj at pos1 ?
        return ustC.fetch(pos1);
    }

}

//-----------------------------------------

public interface myList<T> {
    T fetch(int index);
}
```

static method handle gets an object (ustC) which is private. How can I
 use methods, compareTo and fetch for this object? I have tried  parametrisation, but if its the right way, I don't know how to solve. 
Thanks for any help.

Comment: *"gets an object (ustC) which is private"* - What? I don't understand what you mean (or where the problem is with the code). How do you "get an object which is private"? As far as I can tell you pass the object as a parameter?

Comment: Hi, the problem is , that the object , which is created from a static private class

Comment: is passed to a method in onother class. But how can I handle it wihtin this method?

Comment: How about you start by telling us which errors this code generates? (Compiler errors, runtime errors, ...)

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "do the exercise"?  What are you attempting to implement, what code has the exercise started with?  What code in the example have you written?  What is the expected behavior, and what behavior are you getting?  Note that `ustC`, as it is being passed in, is an instance of `C`, which is a subclass of `myList`.  `myList` is completely visible to you, and happily stores instances of `C` and exposes their `fetch` method.

Comment: thanks for help.... " myList is completely visible to you"

Comment: this was the essential hint.

Comment: //Solution
    public class ClassD {
          public static <S extends Comparable> S handle(myList<S> ustC, int pos1, int pos2 ){ 
               int y = ustC.fetch(pos1).compareTo(ustC.fetch(pos2));
               return ustC.fetch(pos1);
          }
    }

Comment: Excellent!  I've transcribed my comment and your solution into a proper answer, then.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, `ustC`, by virtue of the way handle is called in this context is of type `C`, which implements the `myList` interface.  This interface exposes the fetch method, and is visible to your handle method.

The modification you arrived at in your comments would allow you to call `fetch`:

```
//Solution 
public class ClassD { 
    public static <S extends Comparable> S handle(myList<S> ustC, int pos1, int pos2 ){
        int y = ustC.fetch(pos1).compareTo(ustC.fetch(pos2)); 
        return ustC.fetch(pos1);
    } 
}
```